# Not getting native resolution of external monitor in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, external-display, resolution

Since there us a defect in my laptop screen, I am using an external Dell 1600x1000 monitor. Windows was recognizing the native resolution correctly. But when I installed Ubuntu 10.10, I get only up to 1024x768 in the Monitor preferences. I had a look at [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-adjust-screen-resolution-on-ubuntu.html) and tried to add resolution by running

```
xrandr --addmode VGA 1600×1000
```

but I am getting the error

```
xrandr: cannot find output "VGA"
```

What is the way out.

Comment: What is the output you get from running just xrandr? ("$xrandr")

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `xrandr` and check that the output name is indeed `VGA`. Sometimes it will be `VGA1`. If you don't see `VGA` nor `VGA1`, it might be because your X configuration and/or X video driver were really unable to detect or enable the VGA output.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this on several machines.  There are many web hits for this issue, so apparently many others are having the problem, but very few with correct and complete information.  Usually it is necessary to add a suitable mode, which requires the "cvt" utility to generate the "modeline".  Useful web pages include:

[UbuntuGeek on using xrandr with GDM](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) and [vr-zone on using xrandr with ~/.xprofile](http://forums.vr-zone.com/mobile-computing-tablets-notebooks/491578-howto-ubuntu-linux-users-using-netbooks-external-monitors.html).

You can probably find others with a search that includes "xrandr", "cvt", and "modeline".